# when i am entering $time=strftime('%c'); it showing value 00:00:00 in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","admin");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$time=strftime('%c');
 $sql="INSERT INTO bookreserve(libid,bookid,issuedate ,time)
VALUES
('$_POST[libid]','$_POST[bookid]','$_POST[issuedate]','$time')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  echo "wait for conformation";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

when i am seeing mine bookreserve table the value is sill 00:00:00 in time column

Comment: Show us an example of what `$sql` looks like (i.e. `echo $sql;`). Also, what type is the column in the database?

Comment: Sun Mar 30 14:14:23 2014 kind of string will be returned by $time=strftime('%c'); check your datatype of time

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 1):

Either you've chosen the wrong modifier for `strftime()` as the time field must be in HH:mm:ss format. In which case you want:

```
$time=strftime('%H:%i:%s'); // date('H:i:s') would probably also suffice
```

Or you've chosen the wrong data type for your database column. If you really want the date in %c format you should change it to be a varchar. (I think `varchar(23)` should work).

You could also just change your query to use MySQL's own functionality:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO bookreserve(libid,bookid,issuedate ,time)
VALUES
('$_POST[libid]','$_POST[bookid]','$_POST[issuedate]',NOW())";
```